# Connect MySQL Using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using the following string to connect to mysql database on a localhost ( I do not have root access). I DID read related posts on Stack Overflow.

I defined this the php file:

```
ini_set('mysqli.default_socket', '/tmp/mysql5.sock');
ini_set('mysql.default_socket', '/tmp/mysql5.sock');
ini_set('pdo_mysql.default_socket', '/tmp/mysql5.sock');
```

When I use:

```
'mysql:localhost:/tmp/mysql5.sock;dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset=utf8'
```

or

```
'mysql:unix_socket:/tmp/mysql5.sock;dbname='.DB_NAME.';'
```

I got this

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory

When I use:

```
'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname='.DB_NAME.';'
```

I got this

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Anyone can take a look, thanks so much!!

Comment: i don't know why you try to use `ini_set()` to setup sockets and use them. in your connection strings you are missing the username and password. try something like this in your connection string: `$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.DBNAME, 'user', 'password');`

Comment: Is your server even up? Does `/tmp/mysq5.sock` exist? Can you confirm that you can connect to it using other tools?

Answer (score 1):

as i mentioned in my comment, i really don't know why you want to use sockets for your `MySQL`connection. plus, in your trials you are always missing a username and password. so please try something like this:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.DBNAME, 'user', 'password');
```

Answer (score 1):

i've the same issu and resolved it with adding 'unix_socket' in host, like this :

```
$host = 'localhost;unix_socket=/tmp/mysql5.sock';
```

so you will have

```
'mysql:host=' .$host .';dbname='.DB_NAME.';'
```